# Devise and Sidekiq automatically routing me to the Sidekiq dashboard on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I have a Rails 7 app using devise and Sidekiq for emails. Only an admin is allowed to access the Sidekiq dashboard.

Here is an excerpt from my routes file.

```
       root to: "scores#new"

       devise_for :members, controllers: {registrations: 'members/registrations',
                                 sessions: 'members/sessions',
                                 passwords: 'members/passwords'}

       devise_scope :member do
          authenticated :member do
            root :to => 'scores#new', as: :authenticated_root
          end
          unauthenticated :member do
            root :to => 'members/registrations#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
          end
       end

       require 'sidekiq/web'

       authenticate :member, ->(member) { member.user.admin? } do
          mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
       end
```

As soon as I sign up (recognised as an admin), it roots me to the Sidekiq dashboard. Then if I sign up as a non-admin, it still "tries" to root me to the Sidekiq dashboard and fails.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try another approach. If you want to manage the access to different resources based on user privileges across your whole application, you could use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem. That would keep the `routes.rb` cleaner, without overloading it with logic.
Also, it's not a best practice to check for user privileges in routes.